# MVC 1.0, .Net 4.0, and Expression Blend 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, expression-blend, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to open a MVC 1.0 project compiled with the .net 4.0 framework in Expression 4.  The solution opens fine, but there is no intellisense and when I run it, it shows an html browse page with the files listed.  Any ideas on how to get Expression 4 to play nice with MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up buying the designer a Visual Studio 2010 license.